# WorkManager running every x minutes with new parameter

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I need to make an API call every X minutes, but it needs new int value each time that is needed in the API call when the worker runs?

So far, through the examples [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#params), it seems like, it will run the same call, with the same parameters every X minutes.

I need to pass a different value each time this job is going to run?

Comment: Which kind of new data you're referring to?

Comment: a simple int value.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for WorkManager? What part do you not understand about it?

Comment: how to send a different value, each time. So for example, if i need to send the lat/long of the device every 30mins(Obviously the lat/long will be different each time?

Comment: Then take lat/lng inside `doWork()` method by yourself every time, why to pass it from outside?

Comment: because there is a getInputData() method and it would mean i would have to put location services in the worker

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can find is by saving the battery level to sharedprefs then pulling the data from shared prefs when I need it.